# How can I handle 301 redirects in a service worker?

Tags: character-encoding, fetch, service-worker, arabic, farsi

On my Persian language website, there are some problems in the handling of **301 redirects** when the **service worker** is fetching some requests with **Persian/Farsi characters**.

As regular, when a user enters a keyword, as for example **رامسر** (Ramsar as English) submits an Ajax search form, a request as below sent to the server (Apache/Laravel):

```
https://www.example.com/s?search=%D8%B1%D8%A7%D9%85%D8%B3%D8%B1&gstnum=1
```

Note that *%D8%B1%D8%A7%D9%85%D8%B3%D8%B1* is Unicode of رامسر.

So, at back-end this request redirects to another URL (301 Redirecting):

```
https://www.example.com/s/ramsar/%D8%A7%D8%AC%D8%A7%D8%B1%D9%87-%D9%88%DB%8C%D9%84%D8%A7-%D9%88-%D8%B3%D9%88%D8%A6%DB%8C%D8%AA-%D8%AF%D8%B1-%D8%B1%D8%A7%D9%85%D8%B3%D8%B1?gstnum=
```

The above is the encoding type of this URL:

```
https://www.example.com/s/ramsar/اجاره-ویلا-و-سوئیت-در-رامسر
```

But, when service-worker is running, it cannot set the correct character setting of respond URL, it returns:

```
https://www.example.com/s/ramsar/Ø§Ø¬Ø§Ø±Ù-ÙÛÙØ§-Ù-Ø³ÙØ¦ÛØª-Ø¯Ø±-Ø±Ø§ÙØ³Ø±
```

This is my code for the fetch method of service-worker:

```
self.addEventListener("fetch", function (event) {
  if (event.request.method === "GET" && event.request.mode === "navigate") {
    event.respondWith(async function () {
      try {
        var networkResponse = await fetch(event.request);
        return networkResponse;
      } catch (error) {
        ...
      }
    }());
  }
});
```

What can I do?

Comment: Well formed question!